# Straight cone inscribed in sphere, surface of sphere given,whats the lateral surface of the cone?

Tags: trigonometry

I am given the following task:

A sphere with surface $O = 200 dm^2$ is a straight cone with the opening angle $y= 34º$ inscribed. Calculate the lateral surface and the volume of the cone.

From what I know is that the surface of the sphere is calculated by $4\pi r^2$,
so $r = 3.99$

The lateral surface of the cone is calculated with $\pi rs$. Now only $s$ is missing. I tried calculating $s$ with $\frac{\sin (\frac{y}{2})}{r} = s$, since $\sin(a) = \frac{opposite}{hypotenuse}$

The correct answer is $53,48dm^2$, calculated with $\frac{O*\sin^2(y)}{4*sin(\frac{y}{2})}$, yet I have no clue what this does and how it works.

Help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radius of the cone will not be the same as the radius of the sphere. Taking a cross section ( assuming a right cone here, btw), we can see that the angle the base chord will subtend at the centre is $2*34^o = 68^o$

Hence the radius of cone $r_c = r_s\sin(68/2) = r_ssin(34^o)$

The lateral side length is given as $s = r_c/\sin(34/2) = \frac{r_s\sin(34)}{\sin(17)}$

Hence lateral surface L is given as

$$L = \pi r_c s = \frac{\pi * r_s \sin(34) * r_s\sin(34)}{\sin(17)} $$

If you express this in terms of O, you will get the expression required

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer, would you mind explaining a bit further how your calculation for the radius of the cone works, and for which triangle the 68 degrees are? I'm sorry if this seems very clear to you but I'm not very good at math...

Comment: If you take a cross section of a cone in a sphere, you'll get a triangle in a circle. The diameter of the cone would be equal to the length of the base of this triangle. Join the end points of this base chord to the centre of the circle, and you'll get the relationship